# File upload error in asp.net mvc controller ('HttpRequestMessage' does not contain a definition for 'Files'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, jsajaxfileuploader

I have a controller link to an input element for uploading. In my controller I am getting a weird error that I do not quite understand. Severity    Code    Description Project Path    File    Line    Suppression State

> Error CS1061  'HttpRequestMessage' does not contain a definition for
>   'Files' and no accessible extension method 'Files' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'HttpRequestMessage' could be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   SimSentinel C:\Users\tsach\Source\Workspaces\SIMSentinelv2\Website\SimSentinel\SimSentinel\Controllers  C:\Users\tsach\Source\Workspaces\SIMSentinelv2\Website\SimSentinel\SimSentinel\Controllers\BulkSMSUploadController.cs

```
    using System.Data;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web.Http;
    using System.Web.Security;
    using Repositories.Interfaces;
    using Repositories.Interfaces.Dtos;
    using SimSentinel.Models;
    using System;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Schema;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    //using System.Web.Http.HttpPut;


    namespace SimSentinel.Controllers
    {
        [System.Web.Http.Authorize]
        public class BulkSMSUploadController : ApiController
        {
          public ActionResult Index()
          {
             //ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

             //return View();
             return null; 
          }

          [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
          public ActionResult UploadFiles()
          {
             if (Request.Files.Count <= 0)
             {
                return Json("No files selected.");
             }
             else
             {
                try
                {
                   HttpFileCollectionBase files = Request.Files;
                   for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
                   {
                      string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Uploads/";
                      string filename = Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[i].FileName);

                      HttpPostedFileBase file = files[i];
                      string fname;
                      if (Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "IE" || Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "INTERNETEXPLORER")
                      {
                         string[] testfiles = file.FileName.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
                         fname = testfiles[testfiles.Length - 1];
                      }
                      else
                      {
                         fname = file.FileName;
                      }

                      fname = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"), fname);
                      file.SaveAs(fname);
                   }

                   return Json("File Uploaded Successfully!");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                   return Json("Error occurred. Error details: " + ex.Message);
                }
             }
          }

          //public ActionResult About()
          //{
          //   ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";

          //   return View();
          //}
       }
    }
```

So after all this I have adjusted my controller. See code below which works however it redirects to the actual controller and that is a problem in a SPA application. In addition, the file also saves in a wierd format almost like a randomly generated string like BodyPart_2ea18b56-0c11-41f6-81ff-204bb377cbbf

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

public class Upload2Controller : ApiController
{
   public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFormData()
   {
      // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
      if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
      {
         throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
      }

      string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Files");
      var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

      try
      {
         // Read the form data.
         await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

         // This illustrates how to get the file names.
         foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
         {
            Trace.WriteLine(file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName);
            Trace.WriteLine("Server file path: " + file.LocalFileName);
         }
         return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
      }
      catch (System.Exception e)
      {
         return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
      }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be careful on following steps.

- Make sure your form html element has `enctype = "multipart/form-data"`
  So it should be something like `<form action="someaction" enctype = "multipart/form-data"> </form>`

I usually use html helper..

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "JobApplication", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data", @id = "myForm", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
    {
// your input datas
}
```

- If you would like to post image or some document, insead of using request, you should use `public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }` in your ViewModel. Then you can easily use it on your razor.

  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new { @type = "file", @onchange = "SomeValidationOnClientSide(this);"})

On the backend side you can validate your case. In my case I only accept PDF files..

```
if ((from file in model.Files where file != null select file.FileName.Split('.')).Any(arr => arr[arr.Length - 1].ToLower() != "pdf"))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "We only accept PDF files!");
            return View(model);
        }
        if (model.Files.Count() > 2)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty,
                "You have exceeded maximum file upload size. You can upload maximum 2 PDF file!");
            return View(model);
        }
```

Edit: I see that you implemented ApiController instead of Contoller. So I understand that you are developing WEB.API, you should add this into question tags as well.

If you would like to develop ApiController, you should send byte[] and process this byte[] into your apiController.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see your controller implements Web API controller (i.e. using  [`ApiController.Request`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http.apicontroller.request?view=aspnetcore-2.1)), which has definition as shown below:

```
public System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage Request { get; set; }
```

The return type is [`HttpRequestMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestmessage?view=netframework-4.7.2) which doesn't have `Files` property, as opposed to intended [`HttpRequestBase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequestbase?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) that implemented as return type of [`Controller.Request`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.request?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) property below:

```
public System.Web.HttpRequestBase Request { get; }
```

To solve this issue, you need to inherit from `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` base class and move Web API requests to another class which inherits `ApiController`, because you cannot inherit both `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` and `System.Web.Http.ApiController` on the same class:

```
namespace SimSentinel.Controllers
{
   public class BulkSMSUploadController : Controller
   {
      [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
      public ActionResult UploadFiles()
      {
         if (Request.Files.Count <= 0)
         {
            return Json("No files selected.");
         }
         else
         {
            try
            {
               HttpFileCollectionBase files = Request.Files;
               for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
               {
                  string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Uploads/";
                  string filename = Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[i].FileName);

                  HttpPostedFileBase file = files[i];
                  string fname;
                  if (Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "IE" || Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "INTERNETEXPLORER")
                  {
                     string[] testfiles = file.FileName.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
                     fname = testfiles[testfiles.Length - 1];
                  }
                  else
                  {
                     fname = file.FileName;
                  }

                  fname = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"), fname);
                  file.SaveAs(fname);
               }

               return Json("File Uploaded Successfully!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               return Json("Error occurred. Error details: " + ex.Message);
            }
         }
      }
   }

   [System.Web.Http.Authorize]
   public class BulkSMSUploadWebApiController : ApiController
   {
       public IHttpActionResult Index()
       {
           return null; 
       }
   }
}
```

If you want to upload file using Web API controller, you should use `HttpResponseMessage` to retrieve file details with `MultipartFileData` as provided in [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2) (make sure you're checking against `IsMimeMultipartContent` first).

Comment: Thank you all for your help I have had to adjust the code in the controller to get it to work. So the file is now saving but I have run into two extra problems. The file saved with some random string like BodyPart_2ea18b56-0c11-41f6-81ff-204bb377cbbf and after saving redirects to the actual controller itself and this is a problem in SPA application because it means the user has to login again everytime after uploading a file

Comment: I will update my post now to show you what my new controller looks like

Comment: `2ea18b56-0c11-41f6-81ff-204bb377cbbf` seems like a GUID-formatted string (as 8-4-4-4-12 format). I suggest you check `file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName` and `file.LocalFileName` to find out where the additional GUID comes from.